# How to add a sklearn target transformer (for output variable) to keras neural network pipeline?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn

I want to build a neural network using Keras on transforms of my input variables AND my output variables using the sklearn Pipeline (so I can perform CV). I am trying to use TransformedTargetRegressor, but my mean squared errors do not make sense to me.

This is my code which is adapted from Sklearn's example for TransformedTargetRegressor using the Boston Housing dataset and adding a simple neural network that scales the input variables (X).

**Set up (this section is fine):**

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.compose import TransformedTargetRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

#load data
X, y = load_boston(return_X_y=True)

#define simple neural network
def simple_nn():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(13, input_dim=13, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer = 'adam')
    return model

#create pipeline for input variables (X) preprocessing
estimators = []
estimators.append(('standardize', StandardScaler()))
estimators.append(('mlp', KerasRegressor(build_fn=simple_nn, epochs=100, batch_size=5, verbose=True)))
pipeline = Pipeline(estimators)
```

**I am trying to do the following (section in question):**

```
#Section in question
transformer = MinMaxScaler()
model = TransformedTargetRegressor(regressor=pipeline,
                                   transformer=transformer)
results = cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=KFold(n_splits=5))
```

The resulting cross validation scores are:
`array([ 0.61321517,  0.35811762, -2.67674546, -0.30623006, -0.38187424])`

The middle number is of particular concern to me since the y target is supposed to have been scaled from 0 to 1, so a mean squared error of -2.67 seems wrong. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mean squared error is squared, and thus can't be negative.
That means that your score is not the mean squared error.

The [cross_val_score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html) documentation tells us that if not defined, the scorer default to the estimator scorer :

> "If None, the estimator’s default scorer (if available) is used.

In your case, it's the TransformedTargetRegressor regressor that is being used. And the [TransformedTargetRegressor documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.TransformedTargetRegressor.html) tells us that its default score :

> Return the coefficient of determination R^2 of the prediction.

So the values your are displaying are R2 scores. It can be negative if your model perform badly. [See this question for instance.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12900/when-is-r-squared-negative)

As a good practice, you should always define the scorer you want to use, to avoid relying on the wrong one.

Comment: Gotcha, this makes sense. How do I get the mean squared error score then given the estimator in `cross_val_score` is `model` in the above, and 

`model` itself is a `TransformedTargetRegressor` with `pipeline` as its regressor?

Is it just a matter of filling in ??? into the line:

`results = cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=KFold(n_splits=5), scoring=???)`

Generally, is the set up correct in the way I have it?

Comment: I believe it might be `scoring='neg_mean_squared_error'`, though I am still unsure if this is doing the right thing in terms of transforms.

Comment: Yes, you should add `scoring = ‘neg_mean_squared_error’` in `your cross_val_score` to get the MSE.  If you're unsure about your transform, you should test each step independently with controlled input data, e.g input range(10). You can access the different steps of your fitted pipeline like dict (pipeline['standardize'])

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate the help and your time. Think I got it.